# How to get an object to be reactive to animation/change it's shape (like 'damped transfom' in unity)

Tags: unity

I want my objects to have a delayed reaction / change their shape as they react to an animation they're parented to...or alternatively to their own animation.

I found out about the 'damped transform' function that exists in unity:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.animation.rigging@0.2/manual/constraints/DampedTransform.html

Is there an equivalent function in blender?